# Are pointers or memory addresses can be parameters in printf() function?

Tags: c, printf

I got confused making a printing function.

```
void Printing(int* pi, char* pa)
{
    printf("%d", *pi);
    printf("%s", *pa);
}
```

Code above has an error in 2nd `printf()`.
But code below doesn't have. It prints the integer and string well.

```
void Printing(int* pi, char* pa)
{
    printf("%d", *pi);
    printf("%s", pa);
}
```

So far, I gave variables to `printf()`. But I don't understand why I need to give the pointer to the 2nd `printf()`.

Comment: Second printf with `%s` expects a string(sequence of chars) there. That's why you're getting an error.

Comment: if you want to print a char you give the char. but you don't want to print a char, you want to print a string. What is a string?

Comment: If you understand this, you have understood a lot: **Each and every parameter in C is passed by value.** Even pointers are passed by value. If you pass `pa`, printf gets *a copy of the memory address* which tells it where in memory to look for the chain of characters forming the string. If, by contrast, you pass `*pa`, printf gets *a copy of the character at that memory location*, stripped of all information about where in memory the original is: printf never sees the original character, only a local copy. (Of course, since the format `%s` makes printf expect a pointer, it also crashes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code

```
 printf("%s", *pa);
```

should be

```
 printf("%s", pa);
```

as `%s` expects the starting address of a null-terminated character array (i.e., a pointer, not the `char` as you have supplied).

From `C11`, chapter 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf`

> `s`
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating null character. [...]

To add, `*pa` is same as `pa[0]`, which is of type `char`. To print that, you'd need to use `%c` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't understand why I need to give the pointer to the 2nd printf().

Because strings work a little weirdly in C. Technically, there is no type for strings in C. So `const char *`/`char *` is used for strings. The way this works is that the pointer points to the beginning of the string, and the string ends with a NUL character `'\0'`. To visualize it, say you call `Printing` with `Printing(0, "Hello");`, you pass a pointer to the beginning of a string literal which looks like this in memory:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| H | e | l | l | o |END|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And the pointer you pass points to the first character, `H`. If you understand this, you will understand why it needs a pointer. If you dereference it, you will only give the first character `H`, so it won't be able to print the whole string.